# Why is Bandit Queen banned in India?

Tags: distribution, indian-cinema, censorship, bandit-queen

[*Bandit Queen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandit_Queen) is an Indian biographical film based on dacoit Phoolan Devi. I know that she fought to get it banned in India. But what is the exact reason behind this? People generally like biographies of their own lives. Are any movie parts falsely shown? Why did this film get banned in India?

Note - She is saying in this [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyUkMRJvn7c) that some parts are wrongly shown.

<sup>(The interview is in 'Hindi' language)</sup>

Comment: https://www.livemint.com/Leisure/VDNX1GQ7uY2b2v4HYcxRhK/Disgusting-and-revolting-and-obscene-Bandit-Queen-and-t.html

Comment: @Paulie_D why not answer then?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer authoritatively and I'm currently tied up in something else. If no-one else does I'll get around to it later...possibly tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was banned temporarily by the Delhi High Court after Phoolan Devi, the subject of the film's story, challenged its authenticity. Also, it was banned due to sexual content. The movie raises moral questions on individual's right to privacy.

> It all starts with Phoolan, increasingly angry that she is, despite requests, not being shown the film on her life.
>
> On September 6, Phoolan moves the Delhi High Court seeking a ban on its screening. Three days later, the court restrains the producers from screening the film, even in private, and asks them to deposit an unexpurgated version in court and also show it to Phoolan.
>
> The Censor Board orders cuts: four letter words, a large part of the rape sequences, the scene showing Phoolan being paraded naked in Behmai, allusions to policemen raping her.
>
> <sub>[India Today, Shekhar Kapur's 'Bandit Queen' raises moral questions on individual's right to privacy](https://www.indiatoday.in/magazine/special-report/story/19941015-shekhar-kapur-bandit-queen-raises-moral-questions-on-individual-right-to-privacy-809819-1994-10-15)</sub>